# RegEx Name Firsts Letters Uppercase Check

Tags: javascript, regex, forms

Hello Im trying to check with regex if the first letter of a name is in uppercase, i have reach this code as now

```
/^([A-Z][a-z]{3,})([A-Z a-z]*$)/
```

The problem is that the name should contain at leat 4 letters and each word should start with a uppercase letter like this:

> John Gustave Lenn

- Is ok because each first letter is Uppercase and have 4 letters at leat

> John gustave lenn

- Is not ok

im using it on javascript to validate a form entry called name I have:

```
var name_input = document.getElementById("name");
var name_value = name_input.value;
var nameformat = /^([A-Z][a-z]{3,})([A-Z a-z]*$)/;

if(name_value .match(nameformat)){
        alert("OK");
    }else{
        alert("NOT OK");
    }
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression `/^[A-Z][a-z]{3,}( [A-Z][a-z]{3,})*$/` matches one name or several successive names (all with uppercase first letter, next letters must be lowercase), **separated by a single space**
(so `John William     Smith` does not match).

A Javascript implementation:

```
const regex = new RegExp(/^[A-Z][a-z]{3,}( [A-Z][a-z]{3,})*$/);
alert(document.getElementById("name").value.match(regex) ? 'OK' : 'Not OK');
```

Best regards

Comment: Works perfectly just changed to /^[A-Z][a-z]{3,}( [A-Z][a-z]{0,})*$/ to allow the rest of the names be less than 4 charcters

Answer (score 0):

Something of this sort should do I believe:

```
/^([A-Z][a-z]{3,}[ ]*?)+$/
```